# Commerce 9 Bussiness Tools

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-connect

I installed Commerce 9 in a new VM. Everything works fine, but when I am trying to open Bussiness Tools I got next exception :

[image]

In the content editor I could see all categories and products.

[image]

Comment: Have you populated the *AllowedOrigins* property to include the domain your accessing the Business Tools?

Comment: I assume based on the screenshot that youhave BixFx site different to localhost:4200. It appears from exception that authoring site is trying to access your BizFX site. Can you add authoring url with http and https at the beginning in AllowedOrigin for BizFx?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the config.json of your CommerceAuthoring website such as:

\CommerceAuthoring_Sc9\wwwroot\config.json

In the AppSettings\AllowedOrigins, make sure that an entry to your BizFx's URL is in the list.  It's normally, localhost:4200, but since you changed it, you need to update this config setting.

**UPDATE**

Per Andrey's comment, yes, the URLs are case-sensitive.

Comment: I already changed that values to my own urls

Comment: I tested on my local IIS by adding the https URLs sitecorebizfx.local and commerce-authoring.local.   I updated the corresponding BizFxUri setting in the SitecoreBiz site\assets\config.json.  I then updated the IdentityServer appsettings.json's AllowedCorsOrigins, PostLogoutRedirectUris, and RedirectUris to point to the new BizFx url.  Lastly, I added the https://sitecorebizfx.local in the CommerceAuthoring's config.json. (I also updated the Business Tools url in SC's core to sitecorebizfx.local).  I logged in to SC, clicked on Business Tools, logged in and worked.

Comment: The host name should be exactly in the same format as the bizFX url, means that if you have a `https://MyBizFx.url`, and you request it from `https://mybizfx.url`, it won't work. 
please, add that to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Can you make sure you have done all of the following steps:

1. Update the BizFxUri parameter in SitecoreBizFx\assets\config.json in your BizFx instance.
2. Update the AllowedOrigins parameter in wwwroot\config.json in your Commerce Engine instance. Double check here to make sure the protocol is **https** and not http.
3. Replace the default URL (localhost:4200) in the RedirectUris, PostLogoutRedirectUris, AllowedCorsOrigins parameters in SitecoreIdentityServer\wwwroot\appsettings.json in your Identity Server instance.
4. Reset IIS.
5. Finally, clear all browser cache and try again. This last step is important.

Comment: the problem of my issue was some sitecore custom code (routing), after I removed the custom code it works fine.