# CORS error when loading Business Tools

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Business Tools is not loading and getting these errors in the console:

[image]

> bizfx.sc910.qa/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://commerceauthoring.sc910.qa/api/GetNavigationView()' from
>   origin 'https://bizfx.sc910.qa' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. main.5586ec01dfda60eddd87.bundle.js:1 Http failure response
>   for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error n.handleError @
>   main.5586ec01dfda60eddd87.bundle.js:1
>   vendor.7eaf8fb3759d3e45cc81.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in
>   promise): Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error
>       at new V (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at N (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at N (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.7eaf8fb3759d3e45cc81.bundle.js:1)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at n.runTask (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at _ (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.invoke (polyfills.9d27157941ed2fdedcdc.bundle.js:1)

Using `Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.1`

Comment: Are you using valid certificates or self signed certificates?

Comment: I think that this could be a duplicate of this issue -> https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12823/commerce-9-bussiness-tools. Please take a look and resolve based on answers.